# Range bar speed

Tags: javascript

I have a range bar from 0 to 100 which controls the reading speed of a file.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOYlJ.png)

The thing is the value 0 means the fastest speed and 100 means the slowest.
How to invert this?

I want  the **0 to be the slowest speed    /  100 the fastest speed**

```js
     (function(){
        const pauseButton = document.getElementById("pauseReadingButton");
        const resumeButton = document.getElementById("resumeReadingButton");
        const uploadButton = document.getElementById("uploadFileButton");
        
        let displayFileContents = null;
        let interval = null;
        
        const setButtonState = function(isPlaying){
            if (displayFileContents) {
                pauseButton.disabled = !isPlaying;
                resumeButton.disabled = isPlaying;
            } else {
                pauseButton.disabled = true;
                resumeButton.disabled = true;
            }
        };

        const pauseReading = () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            setButtonState(false);
          }
        
        pauseButton.addEventListener("click", pauseReading)

        const resumeReading = () => {
            if (displayFileContents){
                interval = setInterval(displayFileContents, document.getElementById("range").value);
                setButtonState(true);
            }
        };

        resumeButton.addEventListener("click", resumeReading);

        const readFile = (file, callback) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = callback;
            reader.readAsText(file);
        };
        
        uploadButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const files = document.getElementById("fileToUpload").files;
            if (!files.length) { return; }
            
            readFile(files[0], function(e){
                const content = e.target.result;
                const fileContentArray = content.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                let index = 0;
                
                displayFileContents = () => {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fileContentArray[index];
                            ++index;
                    
                    if (index >= fileContentArray.length){
                        displayFileContents = null;
                        pauseReading();
                        setButtonState(false);
                    }
                };
                
                resumeReading();
                setButtonState(true);
            });
        });
        
            setButtonState(false);
        })();
```

```html
<body>
    <input class="buttonupload" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <button id="uploadFileButton">Play</button>
 
       <text style="color:blue" id="demo"> </text> <br><br>


        <button style="margin-top:20px;" id="pauseReadingButton">Pause</button> &nbsp &nbsp
        <button id="resumeReadingButton">Resume</button>
                                                                    
        
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="range" onchange="name=this.value"; oninput="rangeValue.innerText = this.value">
        <p id="rangeValue">0</p>                                                                     
                                                                  
 
</body>
```

#Creating space space space space space space space space space

Comment: You can just do 100 (maximum value) - value

So when the value is 30 for example you do `100 - 30 = 70`

Comment: Can you clarify please?

Comment: The inverted value is `100` (the maxium input value) `-` the value that the user has given. So for example when the gived value is `45` the inverted value is `100 - 45` (55)

Comment: I know its given please dont cyberbully me, I can't edit the comment lol

Comment: Okk
Can you exemplify with the code plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added to the thing stated in the comment section of the answer here is a code snippet:

You can use the same method in your Javascript if you also want to invert the logic behind the scenes

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="range" onchange="name=this.value"; oninput="rangeValue.innerText = 100 - this.value">
<p id="rangeValue">100</p>
```